# How to find Certificate inside Keystore

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keystore, keytool

I have a keystore with 16 certificates inside. different aliases.

When I use this keystore in SiapUi/ReadyApi and hit the url:

> https:x.y.z.com/...

I can see the 200 response successfully.

So,When I view the keystore by:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks
```

I expect to see word **"x.y.z.com"** in CN or SubjectAlternativeName But I couldn't!!!

But I can find:
a.b.z.com and a.y.z.com

Comment: Use `keytool -keystore keystore.jks -storepass mypwd -list -v -alias mykeyalias` to list a specific key.

Comment: Are you using this 'keystore' to validate the server, to authenticate the client, or both? The cert(s) used to validate the server are really a truststore not a keystore, but Java uses the same file formats (and keytool program) for both. If you are validating the server, your truststore must contain an _anchor (cert)_ for the server cert, which is traditionally and usually a root cert, but in most cases is not the actual server cert.